# Should I copy PSR interfaces or add external depndency?

Tags: php, interface, dependency-management

For example, I really like the [Logger Interface](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-3/) by PHP Fig & want to use it as an interface in one of my packages.

I'd rather not add external dependencies (through composer), so I'm thinking about copy+pasting what they have into my own interface, which may have a couple of it's own functions as well.

Is there a good reason to use the package dependency to get the interface instead of copy+pasting the interface?